# Any occasion where .bashrc is favorable to .bash_profile?

Tags: bash, shell, bashrc

I understand the difference between `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` (or `.bash_login` and `~/.profile` for that matter), but is there any particular reason to choose `.bashrc` over `.bash_profile` for bash shell configuration?

From my understanding, configuration such as terminal colors, environmental variables, etc. in `.bashrc` will be re-loaded every time a new bash window is open. `.bash_profile` will only get loaded once at login, and I think that should be enough. Why put anything in `.bashrc` then?

The only reason I can think of is to avoid having to log out of the system for a configuration to be loaded.

I couldn't find an answer besides purely conventional reasons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shell options (from [`shopt`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) or [`set`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Set-Builtin)) are not inherited through the environment. Nor are [aliases](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Aliases). If you want to, for example, enable `failglob` for all your shells, that needs to be in the RC file. An alias could be replaced with an exported function, but there's no workaround for the options.

It is also [conventional & encouraged by the manual to have `.bash_profile` source `.bashrc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Startup-Files), so these configurations that you put in there will be loaded into both login and non-logic shells. If they're only in `.bash_profile`, they might never be loaded into a shell you actually use at all.

Another situation is where you have more complex configuration with actual executable code (for example, some advanced [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-PROMPT_005fCOMMAND)) and want freshly-initialised variables for it to use in each shell. You probably wouldn't want those variables exported at all, or perhaps they are arrays and they can't be.

A final case would be for side-effecting command execution: displaying `fortune` or a to-do list in every new shell. That is not so much "configuration", but it is setting up your shell behaviour.

---

There is also the more general case where `bash` is not invoked as the login shell (because your session manager does something else, or it isn't your login shell, or ...) and your `.bash_profile` would never be processed at all. That may be out of scope for your concern, though.

Comment: So in essence, only variables that were set to the environment by a login shell are in context for a non-login shell? I think this answers my question. Thank you

Comment: Nothing from the profile *other* than exported variables and exported functions will be automatically provided to independent subprocess shells. There may be other variables, etc, that came from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Any functions or aliases you define will not be available in child shells if you only define them in the `profile` files.

You can reload these files using the `source` command without having to log out, but this can mangle the PATH a bit if it has been modified. `.` on its own is an alias for `source` but sometimes it gets remapped by sysadmins (not sure of the reason).

This is also why you need to run the source command to create functions and aliases in the running shell, because running the script on its own will create a new shell, then create them in that shell and not in the one you're using.

Comment: Functions can be exported with `export -f` (with Bash).

Comment: I didn't know that. It does add an extra thing to remember to do, though :)

Comment: Just did some research - it might be insecure and leave you with obscure breaks in places, apparently. Shellshock was based on exported functions, but I believe that was fixed.